# How can I tell whether a Python dictionary contains a given key? How can I retrieve the associated value?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm working on homework for Programming Fundamentals 1 and I'm having trouble with the assignment

The assignment I'm working on is In-Class exercise 7. I'm stuck with question 3 and 4.

> 3. Assume the variable dct references a dictionary. Write an if statement that determines whether the key 'James' exists in the
>      dictionary. If so, display the value that is associated with that key.
>      If the key is not in the dictionary, display a message indicating so.
> 4. Assume the variable dct references a dictionary. Write an if statement that determines whether the key 'Jim' exists in the
>      dictionary. If so, delete 'Jim' and its associated value.

This is the I did. I don't know if I got this right. Can anyone explain it to me?

```
def main():
    mydict={'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
    mydict = {}
    mydict = {'James'}
    mydict = {'Jim'}

main()
```

Comment: Did you "Write an if statement"? I don't see any here. What are you stuck on?

Comment: Is this a joke of some kind? You haven't done one single thing what the assignment asks. Even the variable name is wrong.

Comment: Sorry I just don't know what to do. I didn't understand the homework.

Comment: You should really speak to your teacher, rather than asking here.

Comment: You what forget it. I hate failing the class and what I don't like when get a bad grade is because I keep failing the class. If anyone don't want to help me. I'll find it myself.

Answer (score 2):

```
from __future__ import print_function  # just for making sure that
                                       # the below works for Python 2 and 3

# print value associated with key 'James' in dct, if that key is in dct
if 'James' in dct:
    print(dct['James'])
else:
    print("'James' isn't a key in dct.")

# delete key 'Jim' and associated value if in dct
if 'Jim' in dct:
    del dct['Jim']
```

See the sections on dictionaries in [the official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) and in [the Python standard library documenation](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict). Also, you might want to read up on [`if` statements](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements).

Answer (score -1):

Hi Poone Kricanakarin.

I believe this snipet can answer your question number 3:

```
dct = {"James1": 1, "Leon": 2, "Eva": 3}
keys = dct.keys() # This is the main point to your answer
James_in_keys = False
for key in keys:
    if key == "James":
        print dct[key]
        James_in_keys = True
if not James_in_keys:
    print "The key ""James"" is not in the dictionary"
```

I guess that you didnt understand the assigngment probably because you didn't know the "keys()" command that appears in the code below and which returns to you a list with all the keys in the dictionary.

I believe that with this you can easily answeer question 4.